# Bug - Can't add an image after clicking Cancel and add another image

Tags: bug, status-completed, uploader

I believe this is a bug. To replicate:

1. Write a post (question or answer)
2. Insert an image and choose to provide it from your computer. Click on the banner to open the file selector and select an image and choose OK (do not drag and drop).
3. You should see a preview.
4. Click on `Cancel and add another image`
5. Attempt to add the same image, again with with file selector. No preview, no option to add it (button remains disabled)

Tried in IE 11 and Chrome 54.

Attempted with .png and .jpg images

The console in dev tools only shows 1 failure of `http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js`

Please note, I keep editing the steps to improve clarity based upon feedback from comments, as such, comments may be out of date

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Any errors in the console? Do you have any plugins/add-ons that you can disable and try again? Anything on the network tab?

Comment: I don't believe my IE is running any plug ins... Please note, I updated my post since removing it from SO @Oded :)

Comment: I saw. Still - no repro here. Can't see this behaviour. Could it be the image?

Comment: I was able to reproduce only when trying to select the same image file again from my computer. Is this what you mean too, @Dave?

Comment: @Oded, and tried with .png and .jpg. Tried to re-add the same image (after clicking cancel).

Comment: Yes @ShadowWizard. If I try to add another image, and then re-attempt the first, it also works. I guess it's trying to prevent uploading the same image twice and going skewy somewhere

Comment: I was trying drag-n-drop, which just works.

Comment: `Drag-n-drop`? Darn kids with your music :)

Comment: Not prevent, it's a technical matter. The whole thing triggers in a `change()` event of the browser's file upload control. If you select same file again, no change occurs. That said, when clicking "Cancel", the control can be reset, what you think, @Oded?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - yeah, that's probably right.

Comment: Bug to fix in around 1 hour!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ShadowWizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) guessed in [his comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287326/bug-cant-add-an-image-after-clicking-cancel-and-add-another-image?noredirect=1#comment932334_287326), the file input was not being cleared when the dialog was being reset.

I have now added that bit to the reset code, and the upload works as expected.